# TFS and MSBuild projects Logging for each project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I'm going build large number (300+) of projects on TFS. I'm considering a proj file to manage these as follows:

```
<ItemGroup Label="GGX_Projects" >
<MyProj Include="$(Source)Proj1.vcxproj"  />
<MyProj Include="$(Source)Proj2.vcxproj"  />
<MyProj Include="$(Source)Proj3.csproj"  />
<MyProj Include="$(Source)Proj4.csproj"  />
<MyProj Include="$(Source)Proj5.vcxproj"  />
```

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(MyProj)" 
         Targets="ReBuid" 
         Properties="Configuration='$(Configuration)'"
         RebaseOutputs="true" 
         ContinueOnError="true"
/>
```

This actually working fine, but one thing I'm unable to achieve i.e. to get Log for each of the projects mentioned in ItemGroup.

I need separate logs, so that if any project fails, that log can be sent via e-mail.

In addition, on msbuild command line, I tried /distributedFileLogger, but unable to understand how to use this to get log file for each project separately.

Is that a correct approach? 
Can anyone please suggest some better solution which could provide separate logging for each project??

Answer (score 1):

Distributed file logger is, as the name suggests, for logging from individual MSBuild nodes within a "distributed" build system, not for logging from individual projects, targets or tasks. You can try creating a simple custom logger, it is fairly trivial, I've written a sample below. Although, you might want to play around with event types for verbosity and use something like `NLog` rather than appending to files as you might get locks.

`msbuild PerProjectLogger.sln /logger:PerProjectLogger\bin\Debug\PerProjectLogger.dll`

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;

namespace PerProjectLogger
{
    public class Logger : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Logger
    {
        public override void Initialize(IEventSource eventSource)
        {
            var loggers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, FileInfo>();

            eventSource.AnyEventRaised += (s, a) =>
            {
                var property = a.GetType().GetProperty("ProjectFile");
                if (property == null)
                    return;

                var project = property.GetValue(a) as string;
                if (project == null)
                    return;

                var logger = loggers.GetOrAdd(Path.GetFileName(project), name => new FileInfo(name + ".log"));
                using (var writer = logger.AppendText())
                    writer.WriteLine(a.Message);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the code. I'll definitely try this. Still searching for some other techniques...

Comment: Do you have any info if TFS has something similar built-in? I'm dealing with 300+ projects here.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed No idea, I'm not overly familiar with the build portion of TFS's ALM. In any case my personal philosophy is anything you do in CI you should be able to do in CLI, e.g. as a dev building locally (the classic offline laptop on an airplane scenario), as a devops debugging remotely, etc. The job of CI is being eye candy and triggering the build/deploy script that does everything it needs to do and is versioned alongside the code itself in VCS, so relying on something that only TFS can do but not local MSBuild is not something I'd recommend [personally].

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this with TFS is to create a single build detention and then on the Process tab you should see an option to pick solutions to build. Here you can add each Project individually. When you do a build the default build process will do a foreach project and build them. You will get a log file in the drop location for each project.

Comment: That would be the last action. Imagine adding 300+ projects individually in TFs.

Comment: That's a nice idea. But have to explore TFS API. Do you have any good link to get a quick idea? Thanks

Comment: 1) http://www.woodwardweb.com/dotnet/tfs_build_api_b.html
2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339575(v=vs.90).aspx
3) http://www.woodwardweb.com/dotnet/tfs_build_api_b_1.html